# How to increment varible names that are already a array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, draw, paintcomponent

I'm trying to code a 2D game, to draw to ground textures I use an Array, but I want to increase the name like from line0 to line1 but I don't know how.

```
BufferedImage line0[] = {/*graphics*/}
BufferedImage line1[] = {/*graphics*/}
BufferedImage line2[] = {/*graphics*/}
BufferedImage lines[] = {
 line0,
 line1,
 line2
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    int rectWidth = GameEngine.PREFERRED_GRID_SIZE_PIXELS; /* ground tile width */
    int rectHeight = GameEngine.PREFERRED_GRID_SIZE_PIXELS; /* ground tile height */

    for(int i = 0; i < GameEngine.NUM_ROWS; i++){ /* NUM_ROWS is the frame height */
        for(int j = 0; j < lines.lenght(); j++){
            /* draw the textures here (lines array) */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you simply access array using the index, like lines[j] ? i.e. lines[0] is just line0 variable...

Comment: I wanted to do that but then i need it 40 times and then if i want to change something it takes really long

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Java Reflections API by getting field names of the class and then getting its value by Field name.

Below is a sample code of how to use reflection. You can modify it to use for your class.

```
Class  aClass = MyObject.class
Field field = aClass.getField("someField");

MyObject objectInstance = new MyObject();

Object value = field.get(objectInstance);

field.set(objetInstance, value);
```

Below is a sample more similar to the type of class you have:

```
public class ReflectionDemo
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        Class<ReflectionDemoClass> clazz = ReflectionDemoClass.class;

        ReflectionDemoClass objectInstance = new ReflectionDemoClass("Avinash", "Sagar", "Stack", "Overflow");

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {   
            Field field = clazz.getField("line"+i);
            Object value = field.get(objectInstance);
            System.out.println(value.toString());
        }
    }
}

class ReflectionDemoClass
{
    public String line0;
    public String line1;
    public String line2;
    public String line3;
    public String lines[] =
    { line0, line1, line2, line3 };

    public ReflectionDemoClass(String line0, String line1, String line2, String line3)
    {
        this.line0 = line0;
        this.line1 = line1;
        this.line2 = line2;
        this.line3 = line3;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont really understand it, can you give me an example for my code?

Comment: Added a more similar example. Hope this helps.